# How to upload xml product feeds using PHP and Amazon SP-API

Tags: php, xml, guzzle, amazon-selling-partner-api

I need to update the quantity data. [I created a feed document and got a response.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIaP3.png)
Now I need to encrypt [xml data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSlf1.png) and upload it. How can I do that? I'm using guzzle 6 to make API requests. I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Guzzle Http Client to upload the document.

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:^7.0
```

Example Code:

```
$options = [
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8'],
    'body' => $content
];

$client = new Client();
$client->request('PUT', $feedURL, $options);
```